# Is it better or not to include anchors in regex capture?

Tags: regex

When a pattern to be captured in a regex is adjacent to an anchor, including the anchors in the capture or not does not affect the captured strings. In the following (Ruby) regex pairs,

```
/(\Afoo)bar/
/\A(foo)bar/

/foo(bar\z)/
/foo(bar)\z/

/foo(^bar)baz/
/foo^(bar)baz/

/foo(bar$)baz/
/foo(bar)$baz/
```

the results are the same. From performance, is it better to include the anchors in the captures, or not, or does it not make difference?

Comment: There should be no difference because anchors are zero-width assertions. It makes no difference what group the empty space goes into, and as for performance, these anchors are used in a consuming pattern in both cases - that should result in the same productivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the practical point of view, the pairs you provide are identical as The point is that the anchors are zero-width assertions that match *empty strings*: `/(\Afoo)bar/` and `/\A(foo)bar/` will match `foobar` at the start of the string while storing `foo` in Group 1, etc.

From the logical point of view, there should be no difference in the productivity as the empty locations at the beginning (`^`, `\A`) and the end (`$`, `\z`) of the line/string are still matched with both regex versions.

In practice, this is the result of [benchmarking](https://ideone.com/OX7HtF):

```
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
    x.report { 500000.times { a = 'foobar'[/(\Afoo)bar/] } }
    x.report { 500000.times { a = 'foobar'[/\A(foo)bar/] } }
end
```

are

```
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.630000   0.000000   0.630000 (  0.628344)
   0.620000   0.000000   0.620000 (  0.628949)
--------------------------- total: 1.250000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.640000   0.000000   0.640000 (  0.635875)
   0.630000   0.000000   0.630000 (  0.627771)
```

Saying that moving the anchor out of the capturing group makes matching a tiny bit faster. **However**, with smaller time values, the [results vary](https://ideone.com/5qiPsT). I think the difference is really negligent.